# Is it cost effective to purchase a frame and components separately?

Tags: product-rec, frames

I was looking to buy a new MTB and was wondering if a purchase of a frame and components separately was cheaper then buying a bike with everything?  I would assembling everything myself instead of a LBS.

I suppose the bike manufacturers get volume discounts for some stuff, but not sure if they pass along those savings or not.

Comment: I think you are going to find the answer to cost and more in this question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/building-from-scratch-vs-buying-new/1454

Comment: @Gary.Ray Darn, missed that